# How execute a FQL Insights query with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I try without success to execute a FQL query using Graph API to get the value of Insights counters.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I use "Facebook C# SDK" version 5.4.1, C# 4.0.

If I use C# sample code provided in the documentation

```
    var fb = new FacebookClient(m_accessToken);
    dynamic result = fb.Query("SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid= me()");
```

I receive a good response

```
{"name":"","uid":100002632407830}
```

With the same syntax, If I request "pages_fans" Insights counter and use **library 5.4.1**

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(m_accessToken);
  dynamic result = fb.Query("SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=6176018219 AND metric='page_fans' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-12-31') AND period=period('lifetime')");
```

I receive always an empty response

```
 {[]}
```

**With the same code but with library 5.2.1**
I receive always a good response

```
 {[{"metric":"page_fans","value":"125535"}]}
```

It is the same problem described here : [Error with FQL query with library 5.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602419/error-with-fql-query-with-library-5-4-1) but with another syntax.

Currently I use FQL Insights queries using REST API (with libary 5.2.1) but I want to migrate to FQL Insights queries using the Graph API (with library 5.4.1) because the REST API is deprecated.

Where is the bug:

1. In my syntax request?
2. In the "Facebook C# SDK" library?
3. On Facebook server?

Best regards.

Comment: at some point in fb c# sdk, we changed to using graph api for fql instead of rest. that may be the reason for it not working now. can u use the graph explorer and fql and check if u get any results. if u get it using graph explorer could then file a bug in codeplex.

Answer (score 2):

I made a request with the Facebook Graph API Explorer

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights
WHERE object_id=6176018219 AND metric='page_fans' AND
end_time=end_time_date('2011-12-31') AND period=period('lifetime')
```

I receive always an empty response.

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

It is a Facebook's bug.

A bug was created about it on Facebook : http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/232510993491615?browse=search_4f08c675cce9d2265724293

Comment: Note to Googlers: You'll also get this nasty empty response if you use certain metrics.  For example: I get this empty response if I query for the "page_views" metric.  However, if I query for "page_fans", I get an acceptable response.  So weird.  Bug, perhaps?

Comment: Update: It looks like you can only use certain `metric` values with certain `period` values.  If you don't, you may see behavior like the empty data set above.  Documentation of the allowed `metric`/`period` combinations: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to retrieving the info which works reliably

I found another way of retrieving insights which seems to be reliable.
documentation found here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/.

with more options to allow format and period changes - below example.

https://graph.facebook.com/2439131959/insights/application_active_users/[period]?format=json&since=[timestamp]&until=[timestamp]&access_token=[access_token]

period is day, month, week, lifetime.
timestamp has to be a valid PST midnight only.
access_token = could be.
1. nothing for the metrics that don't need permission.
2. app_id|secret_code or
3. your authentication token granted that you have access to the insight data of the application or pages (ie owner or insight users).

C# sdk example:

FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient([appID], [secret]);

```
        DateTime untilDate= (new DateTime([Now].Year, [Now].Month, [Now].Day));
        DateTime sinceDate= (new DateTime([Now].Year, [Now].Month, [Now].Day)).AddDays(-1);
        TimeSpan t = (untilDate- new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        int timestampUntil = (int)t.TotalSeconds;
        t = (sinceDate- new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        int timeStampSince = (int)t.TotalSeconds;



        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbClient.Get([appID] + "/insights/" + [metricID] + "/" + [period] + "?format=json&since="+timeStampSince+"&until="+timestampUntil );
         Console.WriteLine(result["data"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct permissions when you get your Access Token

```
<fb:login-button perms="read_insights"></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: it was such a simple "fix" for my empty response. Thx! I wonder WHY FB simply returns empty data instead of error explaining what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This issue related to **Facebook C# SDK**.

Probably best thing you can do is file a bug on codeplex, and replace usage of `end_time_date` to `"time in seconds"` and `period` to `"lifetime"`.